# Nerd Font icon not rendering on button tag but works on other tags

Tags: html, vue.js, icons, font-face

I have a Nerd Font icon, it's not rendering on `button` tag, but works on other tags like `h1`:

[image: preview]

I have tried nothing yet, no CSS. It's shown on the previous image what I am expecting; the icon should be rendering the desired icon, instead of a box.

```js
<template>
    <main>
        <header class="header">
            <h1>{{ post.data.title }} </h1> <!-- icon here -->
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="info">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <small>u/{{ post.data.author }}</small>
                    </a>
                    <p>{{ post.data.selftext_html }}</p>
                </div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="toggle-info"
                >
                     <!-- icon here -->
                </button>
            </div>
            <div
                class="preview"
                @click="zoom = !zoom"
                :class="{ zoom: zoom }"
            >
                <img :src="post.data.url_overridden_by_dest" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `button` was not inheriting the font I'm using. Adding `font-family: "font name"` to the button fixed the issue.